# Switching to the most active window using selenium python

Tags: python, selenium

Is there a way to focus on the latest window open? or switching to the window by getting the current handle of the window?

I was able to print the only window that is opened which is:

```
CDwindow-e8d2af8d-33e8-4538-be6b-6e61f470bf9a
```

Comment: possible to save this in a variable and use self.driver.switch_to_window(variable)?

Comment: tried but did not work

Answer (score 2):

this answer worked for me:

```
driver.switch_to_window(driver.window_handles[-1])
title=driver.title
```